# collections.Counter - can I add/increment individual elements to a Counter?

Tags: python

Can I add/increment individual elements to a Counter?

I am getting each element one by one from an xml parse stream, so my Counter use here is always going to be based on 1-by-1.

OK, I know I can do this:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter("abaa")

print ("counter:", counter)  #('counter:', Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1}))

#and I can do this as well...
def track_data(counter, data):
    counter.update(Counter(data))

#let's say I am in a function that receives data one by one.
one_element_of_incoming_data = "a"
track_data(counter, one_element_of_incoming_data)
print ("counter:", counter)  #('counter:', Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 1}))
```

but what I really want to do is to increment without building a new counter:

```
counter.increment(one_element_of_incoming_data)
```

and see my count for 'a' go up by one.  It doesn't look like it's in the Counter API, am I missing something?

Yes, I know that I could use a defaultdict and increment myself, but I was kinda expecting this capability out of a Counter.

Comment: Counter is just a subclass of dict. Anything you can do with a dict, you can do with Counter.

Comment: Actually, it works like a `defaultdict(int)`

Comment: 90% of the time you can just try what you *hope* will work in Python and it will work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - correct, but I did not intuit the `+=` bit at all.

Comment: @JLPeyret Search your feelings. "JL Peyret, you've turned off your documentation tab, is everything alright?"

Comment: 8-/   feelish sheepish but thanks y'all.  I was actually looking at Python Module of the Week, since their examples are usually less terse than the base doc.  In this case, they did not cover it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
for s in 'abcdefga':
    counter[s] += 1
```

In this way, `Counter` works like a `defaultdict(int)`.  However, it also has some handy methods since it is made to work with counts of things (e.g. you can add two `Counter`s together, it has a more convenient constructor, etc.).

Comment: They key thing to remember is that Counter is pretty much a `defaultdict(int)` with all these other lovely methods specifically for counting and dealing with counts.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri -- Right, but then `.update` might not work the way you want it to and you don't get all of the extra facilities that `Counter` give you for free (e.g. the ability to add/subtract other `Counter`s).

Comment: genius and most *Pythonic*.  I knew my approach was missing something.  I had tried `counter['a'] = 1` to increment, missed the need for a `+=`.  Wished the doc covered it.

Comment: @JLPeyret -- The documentation _does_ cover it (it's the [first example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects))  :-)

Comment: @mgilson - my bad, you are correct.  missed it somehow while looking over the overall api.

Comment: @JLPeyret -- Yeah.  This one feature of `Counter` isn't used _too_ frequently since the constructor/`.update` are so common.